# what is wrong with my t-sql syntax/understanding of the microsoft T-sql syntax documentation

Tags: sql-server, t-sql

I am trying to add a check constraint that WILL NOT be applied to existing records. My attempt at this is:

```
ALTER TABLE myDB.dbo.myTable 
  ADD CONSTRAINT myConstraintName WITH NOCHECK (dbo.myFunction() = 0);
```

returns

> Msg 156, Level 15, State 1, Line 1
>   Incorrect syntax near the keyword 'with'.
>   Msg 319, Level 15, State 1, Line 1
>   Incorrect syntax near the keyword 'with'. If this statement is a common table expression, an xmlnamespaces clause or a change tracking context clause, the previous statement must be terminated with a semicolon.

I am also trying to get the hang of the T-SQL syntax diagrams. Based on the [alter table](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms190273.aspx) syntax and the T-SQL [conventions](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms177563.aspx) it seems like I am following the switches in the syntax diagram the way it is shown in the picture below--leading to the label `<table_constraint>`. I am interpreting as a label for an additional diagram for table_constraint.

1. How do I fix the syntax in the T-SQL statement?
2. Am I interpreting the diagram correctly?

[image]

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Your `WITH NOCHECK` needs to be after your ALTER TABLE statement and you need a `CHECK` to indicate the constraint type.

`ALTER TABLE myDB.dbo.myTable with NOCHECK  ADD CONSTRAINT myConstraintName CHECK (dbo.myFunction() = 0);`

You can then later check against the constraint with

`ALTER TABLE myDB.dbo.myTable CHECK myConstraintName`